# How to get View to recognize initial orientation (iOS)

Tags: ios, coordinate

I have an application that combines both UIView's and GLES views together for rendering.  When the device starts up in landscape mode, all the code I currently have detects the orientation and adjusts the Bounds/Frame accordingly to the right values - but the coordinate system still assumes it is in a portrain mode.  If I then physically rotate the display, the coordinate system becomes in sync with the orientation.

How can I get the coordinate system to 'reorient' to the correct orientation on startup?